# Computationally challenging conundrum regarding Docker Machine

Tags: macos, docker, virtual-machine, virtualbox, boot2docker

I keep getting this error when I try to create the virtual machine in the Terminal on my MacBookPro:

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox dev
Running pre-create checks... Creating machine... Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: exit status 1
```

I have virtualbox installed as well as docker, so I'm not sure what the problem is.
I tried switching from virtualbox version 5 to 4. something, still the same error.
I googled the error and nothing came up.
Why is this happening to me?

Comment: What happens when you open up VirtualBox and manually start the VM?

Answer (score 0):

Run this script for uninstall all about virtualbox/docker and try install Docker Toolbox again...

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/docker*
pkill VirtualBox
pkill VBox
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Kitematic/
rm -rf ~/.docker
rm -rf ~/Library/VirtualBox/
rm -rf ~/Kitematic
$DIR/VirtualBox_Uninstall.tool
```